# How to make permenant edits to GRUB parameters

Tags: boot, grub2

I've just upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04, which threw an error on boot of not finding the root filesystem. I fixed this by pressing "e" at the grub bootloader, and editing `ro quietsplash` to `rw quietsplash`. However, I have to do this at each boot, and can't figure out how to make it permanent.

I'm aware of the file at `/etc/default/grub`, but that only allows you to add parameters, not edit existing ones. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Blaine, your comment that you cannot edit existing parameters in `/etc/default/grub` is incorrect. You *can* edit that file: that's its purpose.

However, to make these changes **permanent** you need to update grub with the `sudo update-grub` command after editing and saving the `grub` file.

Comment: oh! In that case, how would I change ro to rw in that file? ro does not exist anywhere

Comment: My error. I reread your question, which I misinterpreted. My comment about saving grub edits using the `update-grub` command is still valid. However, you're asking about RO/RW permissions to resolve disk errors. First off, I'd highly advise against this (the force to RO is intended to protect filesystem state). That said, I'd recommend reading this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/468846/permanent-grub-edit-from-ro-to-rw which I believe should help you more directly. Good luck!

Comment: thank you! will do. I'd rather not change it, but that's the only way to get my OS to boot for some reason